# Call selector from nother class - Swift 3

Tags: swift, class, uibutton, selector

I'm creating an UIbutton from "Utils_class", and return it to my "getBtsDetails" class.
I successfully achieve to call "buttonAction" function implemented into "getBtsDetails", but then it return an error

> "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
getBtsDetails :

let Utils_Class = Utils()
var labelY : Int = 90

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    WS_Class.GetDiplomaSubject(id: Int(self.BTS_id)!) { number, responseObject, error in
        if((error) == nil) {

            #let's create an UIbutton from Utils_class which gonna call the buttonAction below
self.scrollview.addSubview(self.Utils_Class.createButton(text: "Calcul", buttonY:self.labelY+30))
            self.scrollview.contentSize.height = CGFloat(self.labelY+40)
        }
    }
}

@objc func buttonAction(_ sender:UIButton!)
{
    #the error occurs here
    print(self.Utils_Class.getTextFields(view : self.scrollview)/1)
}
```

And my second class, Utils :

```
public func createButton(text: String!, buttonY: Int!) -> UIButton {
    helpClasses = GetBTSDetails.init()
    let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:buttonY, width:self.screenWidth/5, height:15)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    button.setTitle(text, for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.tintColor = UIColor.black
    button.addTarget(btsClasse, action: #selector(btsClasse.buttonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}

var btsClasse: GetBTSDetails!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't init it

```
var btsClasse: GetBTSDetails!
```

so when target runs

```
button.addTarget(btsClasse, action: #selector(btsClasse.buttonAction(_:)),for: .touchUpInside
```

what in `buttonAction`  will be nil , so you have to link`btsClasse` object to the presented instance that you reference the selector from

Comment: So, is it just necessary to add : btsClasse = GetBTSDetails.init() right ? Thank you !

Comment: if **GetBTSDetails** is  in IB this will crash also , don't know how you show details , but when you show it segue/present/push assign that var variable to self from the one that you show it from

Answer (score 1):

Ok,  i finally succeed, by simply creating a new instance of my class and replacing :

```
var btsClasse: GetBTSDetails!
```

by

```
var btsClasse = GetBTSDetails()
```

This way, my class "GetBTSDetails", all functions, variables are already initialized allowing myself to call the UIButton action.